# compare the first and last observation in each group

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,3),rep(4,3),rep(5, 2)), score = c(30, 10, 22, 44, 50, 5, 20, 1,35, 2, 60, 14,5))

   group score
1      1    30
2      1    10
3      1    22
4      2    44
5      2    50
6      3     5
7      3    20
8      3     1
9      4    35
10     4     2
11     4    60
12     5    14
13     5     5
```

I wish to compare the first score and last score in each group, if the last score is smaller than the first score, then output the group number. The expected output should be like:

```
group 1 3 5
```

does anyone have idea how to realized this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
# First split the data frame by group
# This returns a list
df.split <- split(df, factor(df$group))

# Now use sapply on the list to check first and last of each group
# We return the group or NA using ifelse
res <- sapply(df.split, 
       function(x){ifelse(x$score[1] > x$score[nrow(x)], x$group[1], NA)})

# Finally, filter away the NAs
res <- res[!is.na(res)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, score[1] > score[.N], by = group][V1 == TRUE]

##    group   V1
## 1:     1 TRUE
## 2:     3 TRUE
## 3:     5 TRUE
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, group[score[1] > score[.N]], by = group]

##    group V1
## 1:     1  1
## 2:     3  3
## 3:     5  5
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, .BY[score[1] > score[.N]], by = group]
```

---

As per @beginneR's comment, if you don't like `V1` you could do

```
df2 <- as.data.table(df)[, .BY[score[1] > score[.N]], by = group][, V1 := NULL]
df2

##    group
## 1:     1
## 2:     3
## 3:     5
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that every group has at least 2 observations:

```
newdf <- merge(rbind(df[diff(df$group) == 1 ,] , df[dim(df)[1], ]), 
           df[!duplicated(df$group), ],
           by="group")

newdf[which(newdf$score.x < newdf$score.y), 'group']
#[1] 1 3 5
```

`df[diff(df$group) == 1 ,]` identifies the last observation of each group, except for the last group, which is why I `rbind` the last entry (i.e. `df[dim(df)[1], ]`).  Then, the first observation of each group is given by `df[!duplicated(df$group), ]`.  We merge these on the group column, then identify which ones meet the criteria.

Another option for the `merge` step:

```
merge(df[which(!duplicated(df$group))+(rle(df$group)$lengths-1),],
  df[!duplicated(df$group), ],
  by="group")
```

Answer (score 1):

One more base R option:

```
with(df, unique(df$group[as.logical(ave(score, group, FUN = function(x) head(x,1) > tail(x, 1)))]))
#[1] 1 3 5
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group) %>% filter(first(score) > last(score)) %>% do(head(.,1)) %>% 
 select(group)

#  group
#1     1
#2     3
#3     5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm plyr package fun..

```
library(plyr)
df1<-ddply(df,.(group),summarise,shown=score[length(group)]<score[1])
subset(df1,shown)

group shown
1     TRUE
3     TRUE
5     TRUE
```